# How to get data from l10n in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to get child data from arb file?

file .arb here:

```
"@appBarTitle": {
    "description": "Text shown in the AppBar"
},
```

I try l10n. but not find description

I try "pub get" and add "appBar Title" on to file arb but I don't get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this
[https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization[enter](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization%5Benter) link description here][1](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)